# Having clause ...?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

![enter image description here][1]I m working on a database and have some query regarding the having clause.

I have a table as

```
sales 
(
  id number(5) primary key,
  amt number(10),
  house_no varchar2 (10),
  city varchar2 (10)
)
```

My problem is that I want to find the particular sales_id's and its count which have the the `city` and `house_no` same in each entry.

I have tried to solve it but not get to it yet. I am using `oracle 10g`.

Comment: Please post the SQL statement you have so far and explain what is wrong in your question.  Some sample data and expected output would also be good.

Comment: sales id is primary key, how can you expect output as group of city, house_no?

Comment: Okkk i will attach new iage here so that u can sort out....

Comment: @Prathamesh07 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/76f64/12

Comment: @Naveen Thanks bro its working.......but i dont get the significance of "inner joining " the table and "having count(*)" it would be more beneficial for me if u explain it ........hav a nic dy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/76f64/12/0)

```
SELECT count(*), s2.house_no, s2.city FROM sales s1
  INNER JOIN sales s2 ON s1.id = s2.id 
  GROUP BY s2.city, s2.house_no
  HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Shows output as

```
| COUNT(*) | HOUSE_NO |   CITY |
|----------|----------|--------|
|        2 |      102 |   Pune |
|        3 |      540 | Sangli |
```

[Reference](https://forums.oracle.com/message/9828782) for GROUP BY clause for multiple columns

Comment: @Prathamesh 07 sales id is primary key, how can you expect output as group of city, house_no?

Comment: he needs also the id's

Comment: let me correct myself.......i jst want the particular count of records which are having both city and house name identical.....

Comment: @Prathamesh07 ok doing wait a minute

Comment: @Naveen ok waitin....

Comment: @Prathamesh07 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/76f64/10

Comment: @Naveen Thanks bro its working.......but i dont get the significance of "inner joining " the table and "having count(*)" it would be more beneficial for me if u explain it ........hav a nic dy.

Comment: @Prathamesh07 here we are getting number of rows by using count(*) and house no, city from sales s1 table and this s1 has to inner join with sales table s2 and this join condition made upon the sales id's, and this inner joined sales s2 table rows are we are grouping by using city and house number. And you want output as whoes rows count is more than 2. So , thats why in having clause mentioned it as count(*) > 1. if we use group by clause then we dont use where clause, only use having cluase only, and here s1 and s2 are alias names of table sales and joined table sales respectively :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select id, cnt
  from (select city, house_no, count(*) as cnt
          from sales t
         group by city, house_no) t,
       sales c
 where t.city = c.city
   and t.house_no = c.house_no
```

**Prathamesh 07**:
Hello Further description of my problem is....

[image: image scenario]

**Solution:**

```
select count(*) as cnt, city, house_no
          from sales t
         group by city, house_no
having count(*)>1
```

Comment: select distinct cnt, city, house_no                             from (select city, house_no, count(*) as cnt
          from sales t
         group by city, house_no) t,
       sales c
 where t.city = c.city
   and t.house_no = c.house_no and cnt>1    Sorry, edit didn't worked...

Comment: @Deepshikha unfortunately its not working it's giving the error as- "Column ambiguisely defined"

Comment: should work with latest edit

Comment: @Prathamesh07 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/76f64/10

Comment: @Naveen Thanks bro its working.......but i dont get the significance of  "inner joining " the table and "having count(*)" it would be more beneficial for me if u explain it ........hav a nic dy.